# Action sheet doesn't having cancel button on iPad

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uiactionsheet, cancel-button

I am using `xamarin.forms`, in my code, I have action sheet it is not having a cancel button in iPad. In iPhone, I can see the cancel button but not in iPad

```
var action = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", null, "string 2","string2");
```

What wrong i has done or is there any default feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected behaviour on iPad - Cancel buttons are removed as the user can tap outside of the sheet to dismiss (cancel) it.

`DisplayActionSheet` on iOS uses `UIAlertController` underneath and the lack of cancel button on iPad is standard behaviour for `UIAlertController`.